# Why can't install tidymodels package in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

My Rstudio is 4.0.4 version, however, it showed that the package was built under R verision 3.6.3.
And I can not use this package. How to solove this problem?

```
library(tidymodels)

Warning message:
"package 'tidymodels' was built under R version 3.6.3"
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidymodels' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace 'recipes' 0.1.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.1.16 is required
Traceback:

1. library(tidymodels)
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

Comment: Select Tools\Check for package Updates ... from the menu and update any packages that require it.

Answer (score 0):

That's a warning. The actual error shows beneath:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidymodels' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace 'recipes' 0.1.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.1.16 is required
```

And it is very clear: you need a more recent version of `recipes` which you can get through `install.packages`. It *could* be that a newer version of the package is not available for your R version, in which case you'll need to install RTools (assuming windows, otherwise not required) and do an installation from source.